# test jade file : ENOENT, no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm triing to test jade file ...

```
jade = require('jade');
html = jade.renderFile('../views/regionGroups.jade');
```

But have error:

```
ENOENT, no such file or directory '../views/regionGroups.jade'
```

The path '../views/regionGroups.jade' is 100% valid. My test.js with this code is in `test` folder which is in the same folder as `views` folder.

Comment: By having path as '../' for jade or any other module is not necessary a valid path as 'current' directory can be different. To test it out - put fullpath, and it will work, so that means your relative is not really relative as current directory is different from what you expect.

Comment: With fullpath it works. My jade fullpath: `/Users/user/Dropbox/nodeApps/projectName/views/regionGroups.jade`. My `testFile` fullpath is `/Users/user/Dropbox/nodeApps/projectName/test/jade_test.js`. And `html = jade.renderFile 'views/regionGroups.jade'` works too. So seemingly  `/Users/user/Dropbox/nodeApps/projectName` is working directory allthough `jade_test.js` is in `test` folder

Comment: Try to just: `res.render('regionGroups');`

Comment: `jade.renderFile('regionGroups.jade')` not working but `jade.renderFile('views/regionGroups.jade')` works